# old HTC android phone can not receive react-native build

Tags: android, react-native, htc-android

I have an HTC Desire 510 running Android 4.4.2.

Earlier in the year, I was able to deploy react-native apps to it, back when `react-native init` still generated `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` in the project root folder.

Today, it seems `react-native init` only generates one `index.js` file in the project folder (as explained in this [release not here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.49.0)).  So now when I run the command `react-native run-android` to deploy my app to my phone, I get the error message:

> Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots:
>   ["C:\Users\John\Projects\ReactNative\htcandroidapp"]

How do I get a react-native app to deploy to my old HTC Desire 510 phone?  I have no problem deploying the react-native app to my newer phones.

---

Here is my android/app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nutriag"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':realm')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: Could you add your android/app/build.gradle file?

Comment: @SNT ok i added the android/app/build.gradle file